# Wrong path to SQLiteDB (or copy) on WinPhone. Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Have installed NUGet packages for Xamarin.Forms for PCL. I have 4 projects for Droid, iOS, Win 8.1 and WinPhone 8.1. Tried to connect my database, but encountered trouble: my Win and WinPhone projects don`t see it or return me the wrong path. Followed official Xamarin.Forms forum.

Interface:

```
public interface ISQLite
{
    string GetDatabasePath(string filename);
}
```

WInPhone Class:

```
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using Baumizer.WinPhone;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_WinPhone))]
namespace Baumizer.WinPhone
{
    public class SQLite_WinPhone:ISQLite
{
    public SQLite_WinPhone() { }
    public string GetDatabasePath(string filename)
    {
        return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
    }
}}
```

This class for selecting info:

```
public class DataBase
{
    SQLiteConnection connection;

    public DataBase()
    {
        connection= new SQLiteConnection(DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetDatabasePath("Database.db"));
    }

    public IEnumerable<Group> GetGroups()
    {
        return connection.Query<Group>("SELECT * FROM [Scedule] WHERE [facultyName] =" + "'" + Data.CurrentFaculty + "'");
    }
}
```

It works well on Android. On WinPhone I get exception of SQLite - *no such table: Scedule*. I open the local directory for emulator where db was - 0Kb.
I put db to *Assets* and set *BuildInAction* to *Content*. What`s wrong? Need help

Comment: Do you _create_ the table somewhere? Or is it an existing database?

Comment: It is existing database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On forum find this code, putted to *OnLaunched(...)* in WinPhone App.cs:

```
if(await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetItemAsync(Data.DataBaseName) == null)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync($"Assets\\{Data.DataBaseName}");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
```

It copies DB if it's not exist, but it is. May be I need to delete DB *0Kb*, but I don't know how to do this.

It's work, OnLaunched():

```
try
        {
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetItemAsync("Scedule.db");
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile =
                    await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync($"Assets\\{"Scedule.db"}");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
```

DB was uncorrectly copied. May be there are any another ways.